# Where can I find an application use history?

Tags: package-management, software-recommendation, software-center

In Windows XP, you can find out how often an installed application was used by going to the **Add/Remove Programs** section.  You can also get an estimate of how often the application was used.

Is there a way to do this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

No there's no facility for this that I know of. The closest you could come would be to see how recently files were accessed, but that access could be by any means not just a user running the program. Give this command a try at a shell prompt:

```
ls -ltu /bin | less
```

On my system it shows which utilities I've used most recently (but it also shows which ones were used most recently in `cron` jobs and scripts). You could do something similar with the files for a particular application, but it wouldn't be very meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

Install `popularity-contest` and run `popularity-contest | grep '<OLD>'` to find all the relatively unused packages.

More info on [Debian's popcon README](http://popcon.debian.org/README)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like something [Gnome Activity Journal](http://live.gnome.org/action/show/GnomeActivityJournal) (Gnome Zeitgeist) could possibly do.  Its supposed to track everything that you do, open files, use apps, browse sites, etc.  With the data being captured, a little filtering the data and a nice UI gets you what you'd be looking for.

Its under development still, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You might try as well running that command on `/usr/bin`, since most graphical applications' binaries are installed there.

`ls -ltu /usr/bin | less`

Comment: This is less effective is `relatime` is set in the mount options, which is the default on Ubuntu.